# is there any way to read a DCF partition in Linux?

Tags: linux, ipod

After the unfortunate upgrade of my `ipod touch 5g` to `ios 9.2` I can no longer manage my photos from Linux.  I used to be able to read/write to the `DCIM` folder and now apple has taken that away.  In windows I can see that the partition with the pictures is `DCF` format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, not as easy as plugging in a usb cable but works fairly well.  
 1. I downloaded the free FileManager by Tap Media from the app store.
 2. In the documents tab I choose the photos/videos I want to send to my laptop - by pressing the "+" button and "Add Photo or Video". (You can choose other file types as well.
 3. Then click the GEAR icon on the bottom right "Settings" and choose "upload by Wi-fi Sync"
 4. This will give you a URL like http://192.168.0.10:8080 (yours may be different this is an example) and you can simply put this address in your web browser.  Note you must be on the same network as the iPod both sharing the same wifi signal.
 5. From this web page select the file(s) you want and click the download button.

6. Speed Hack!  Click your laptops wifi button and create a hotspot.  On the ipod instead of using your normal home network signal connect to the newly created hotspot that your computer is providing (your laptop will not have internet access for this duration but it just a click to get back).  Now go back to the IOS FileManager app and revisit the settings as the web url will be different.  Type this new url in and when you download you will get blazing fast download speeds.  Note, this is not needed if you have really fast wifi at home, then it isn't worth the trouble, but for large files and less than 4Mb download speeds I recommend this final step.  Once done downloading your media, switch wifi on both the iPod and laptop back to your normal connections and delete those media files off the iPod to create more space.